# Can I use a valid visa in a cancelled passport?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, passport-renewals, lost-documents

I lost my passport, filed a First Information Report with the police, and applied for new passport. It will arrive in 5 days, but I found the passport I reported as lost. I visited the local Seva Kendra passport office to tell them I found my passport and they put *passport is cancelled* and *visa if any remains valid* seal on it. Can I travel on the same visa by carrying both passports?

Comment: Generally the country which issues the visa sets the rules when it comes to old passports. You may want to mention which visa you have.

Comment: You asked this question before, with a different account: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122039/lost-passport-found.  Generally, when you want to improve a previous question, use the same account and edit the question.  Even if it's been closed or placed on hold, it can be reopened.  Please don't post a brand new question like this; it makes it hard to keep the site organized.  Also, creating multiple accounts with similar names leads to confusion; I suggest that you [merge them](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).